# Reset index for Google Mini Search Appliance and now no results

Tags: google-search-appliance

A few days ago I reset the index (following instructions from help) on a client's Google Mini Appliance after a complete site redesign. Of course at first there were no search results. But at this point the crawl stats seems to be similar to their previous counts (50k pages indexed). However the search still yields no results.

I have been trying to diagnose the issue. Unfortunately I didn't setup the appliance and am not that familiar with its administration. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

I have tried:

- Restarting the system
- Switching back to the default collection
- Switching back to the default front-end

Feel free to take a look at the site: http://floydmemorial.com/